# some qestions with AtomicStampedReference

Tags: java

there is a exampe:

I want use AtomicStampedReference, but there are some questions I don't understand about compareAndSet() method

```
    public boolean compareAndSet(V   expectedReference,
                                 V   newReference,
                                 int expectedStamp,
                                 int newStamp) {
        Pair<V> current = pair;
        return
            expectedReference == current.reference &&
            expectedStamp == current.stamp &&
            ((newReference == current.reference &&
              newStamp == current.stamp) ||
             casPair(current, Pair.of(newReference, newStamp)));
    }
```

expectedReference == current.reference always false，Because it compares references。
**so why AtomicStampedReference can fix ABA problem？** thanks

```
class Counter {
    private final AtomicStampedReference<Integer> value;

    public Counter(int initialValue) {
        value = new AtomicStampedReference<>(initialValue, 1000);
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value.getReference();
    }

    public int increment() {
        int[] stampHolder = new int[1];
        int current;
        int next;
        do {
            current = value.get(stampHolder);
            next = current + 1;
        } while (!value.compareAndSet(current, next, stampHolder[0], stampHolder[0] + 1));

        return next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that _expectedReference == current.reference always false_?

Comment: there is some problem with my explanation，as in my example above，Counter  initialValue >= 128 or  initialValue  type is Sting

Comment: Ah, know I see your problem. If posted an answer with the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `Counter` class does automatic unboxing of the stored value. You need to declare it as:

```
class Counter {
    private final AtomicStampedReference<Integer> value;

    public Counter(int initialValue) {
        value = new AtomicStampedReference<>(initialValue, 1000);
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value.getReference();
    }

    public int increment() {
        int[] stampHolder = new int[1];
        Integer current;
        int next;
        do {
            current = value.get(stampHolder);
            next = current + 1;
        } while (!value.compareAndSet(current, next, stampHolder[0], stampHolder[0] + 1));

        return next;
    }
}
```

When declaring `Integer current` in the `increment()` method the `current` variable can hold a reference to the `Integer` object stored in the `AtomicStampedReference<Integer>` and therefore the `expectedReference == current.reference` condition can be true.

---

As you have noticed, with

```
        int[] stampHolder = new int[1];
        int current;
        int next;
        do {
            current = value.get(stampHolder);
            next = current + 1;
        } while (!value.compareAndSet(current, next, stampHolder[0], stampHolder[0] + 1));
```

the line `current = value.get(stampHolder);` will unbox the `Integer` value in the `AtomicStampedReference<>` and for int values >= 128 the boxing of `current` in the call `value.compareAndSet(current, next, stampHolder[0], stampHolder[0] + 1))` will create a new `Integer`.

However, with

```
        int[] stampHolder = new int[1];
        Integer current;
        int next;
        do {
            current = value.get(stampHolder);
            next = current + 1;
        } while (!value.compareAndSet(current, next, stampHolder[0], stampHolder[0] + 1));
```

the line `current = value.get(stampHolder)` will just read the reference to the `Integer` value stored in the `AtomicStampedReference<>` and `value.compareAndSet(current, next, stampHolder[0], stampHolder[0] + 1))` will pass **that same** reference as first argument in the call and therefore the condition `expectedReference == current.reference` is true (assuming that no other thread changed the value)

Comment: oh，i get it，itank you very much